# Review queue buttons aren't visible, can't be scrolled to when browser window not full-screen (Chrome)

Tags: bug, review

Since the redesign, I have a problem.  I use Chrome on Linux principally, and can test on Windows and OS X if desired.  I use the browser window at less than full screen size because I have other small windows open.

With the old design, all was well.  But with the new design, when I review the review queues, most of the buttons to click are off the screen.  Only the left-most one is on screen. There is no scroll bar on the bottom to scroll over (and I shouldn't have to scroll anyway; the old design didn't require it).  I have to put the browser into full-screen mode to make the buttons reappear.

Where can I post about this problem?  I find it really annoying, and it discourages me from handling review queues since it's more bother.  It's likely that at least some others are also affected.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [Review spring cleaning: performance improvements and responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322183). Basically, the review page is still not yet responsive and they're working on it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323061/review-queue-buttons-arent-visible-cant-be-scrolled-to-when-browser-is-less-t Posted a similar thread in Meta.